# WFS-T geometry name problem OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geometry, wfs-t

I am sending my modified features to database with transactional WFS. The problem is when I render my vector features on map their property name which describes geometry is changed to 'geometry' and geometry column name in database is wkb_geometry(in this case).
So every time I am sending request via WFS-T I have to set geom property name to 'wkb_geometry'

```
feature.set('wkb_geometry', feature.getGeometry());
```

, if I leave 'geometry' response will return :

```
<ows:ExceptionText>No such property: geometry</ows:ExceptionText>
```

Is there some workaround for this because I can't hardcode it this way, some times maybe geometry column name will be something else except wkb_geometry.

Comment: If you have some way of identifying possible names you might be able to search the properties to find the appropriate one:to use from `Object.keys(feature.getProperties())`

Comment: @Mike Yes but the problem is that OpenLayers changes name of my geometry column from data base to 'geometry' property and then I have to reset it back manualy

Comment: does `feature.getGeometryName()` give any clues?

Comment: You can use describeFeatureType to get the geometry name from the wfs